# Bottom Navigation changing selected icon color

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to make a custom bottom navigation in android. 
I wanted to disable the shift and to given custom colors for icons.
The icons are initially grey color and the selected one turns blue.
The problem is that all images stay grey even if they are selected.

I tried to mess with some of it but nothing is making the buttons change color when selected.

Below is the code I tried.

This is the main activity java

```
public class admin extends AppCompatActivity {


BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode((bottomNavigationView));
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

    urgent urgentfragment = urgent.newInstance();
    setFragment(urgentfragment,false);

}



private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bottom_urgent:
                urgent urgentfragment = urgent.newInstance();
                setFragment(urgentfragment,false);
                return true;
            case R.id.bottom_all:
                all allfragment = all.newInstance();
                setFragment(allfragment,false);
                item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.bottom_attendedto:
                attendedto attendedtofragment = attendedto.newInstance();
                setFragment(attendedtofragment,false);
                item.setChecked(true);
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
};

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addtobackstack) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.event_framelayout, fragment);

    if(!addtobackstack)
    {
        for(int i=0;i< fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();++i)
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
    else
    {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

}

This is the main activity xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".admin">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/event_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colors_bottom_navigation"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colors_bottom_navigation"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the helper class that helps disabling the shift

```
   package com.prototypeapp.healer.healer.customviews;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the appearance of color-changing icons by using a [State List Drawable resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList) with PNG images. Let's imagine that you have two differently-colored PNGs:

- `res/drawable-mdpi/ic_share_black_24dp.png`
- `res/drawable-mdpi/ic_share_blue_24dp.png`

You'd then create the State List Drawable, using the **checked** state for the blue icon:

- `res/drawable/ic_share.xml`

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_share_blue_24dp"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"/>

</selector>
```

Now, when you use `ic_share` as the icon for a menu item in your `BottomNavigationView`'s menu, you'll see that the color changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by combining a Vector Drawable with a [Color State List resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource).

The first step is to create the color state list resource, using the **checked** state for the color you want when the bottom navigation item is selected. Here's one using blue and gray:

- `res/color/share_color.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#0000ff" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#1b1b1b" />

</selector>
```

With that in place, you can use this color state list as the color for your vector drawable:

- `res/drawable/ic_share.xml`

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/share_color"
        android:pathData="M18,16.08c-0.76,0 -1.44,0.3 -1.96,0.77L8.91,12.7c0.05,-0.23 0.09,-0.46 0.09,-0.7s-0.04,-0.47 -0.09,-0.7l7.05,-4.11c0.54,0.5 1.25,0.81 2.04,0.81 1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3s-1.34,-3 -3,-3 -3,1.34 -3,3c0,0.24 0.04,0.47 0.09,0.7L8.04,9.81C7.5,9.31 6.79,9 6,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3c0.79,0 1.5,-0.31 2.04,-0.81l7.12,4.16c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.61 1.31,2.92 2.92,2.92 1.61,0 2.92,-1.31 2.92,-2.92s-1.31,-2.92 -2.92,-2.92z" />

</vector>
```

Now, when you use `ic_share` as the icon for a menu item in your `BottomNavigationView`'s menu, you'll see that the color changes.

Note that this requires that you use the [Support Library for vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#sloption) (as opposed to build-time PNG generation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . However I do need to add custom png images . The thing that drives me most insane is that I did the same code in another project and it worked but not this time. Btw on the preview of the layout it also is working...

Comment: @SaraKat I've added another answer to cover using custom PNG images instead of vector drawables